# LinearRegression score

Tags: python

```
#imagem seria um numero(reconhecer caractere)
novo = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
tamanho = cv2.resize(novo, (56, 56))
converter = tamanho.astype('float32')
converter /= 255
onversao = converter.astype('int')
final = conversao.flatten()
classificador = LogisticRegression()
# conjunto de imagens
classificador.fit(x,y)
#passo somente uma imagem
previsao = classificador.predict([final])
#retorna o rotulo da imagem
return previsao
```

O código acima retorna o rótulo referente a imagem passada, mas eu preciso que retorne a porcentagem de acerto.

Answer (score 0):

Do próprio exemplo do [sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
>>> clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs',
...                          multi_class='multinomial').fit(X, y)
>>> clf.predict(X[:2, :])
array([0, 0])
>>> clf.predict_proba(X[:2, :]) 
array([[9.8...e-01, 1.8...e-02, 1.4...e-08],
       [9.7...e-01, 2.8...e-02, ...e-08]])
```

Ou seja, `.predict()` retorna a classe prevista, enquanto [`.predict_proba()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba) retorna a porcentagem de pertencer a cada classe. No exemplo, as classes previstas foram `0` para ambas as 2 entradas, enquanto que as probabilidades foram:

- `[9.8...e-01, 1.8...e-02, 1.4...e-08]`, ou seja, `0.98` de pertencer a classe 0, `0.018` de pertencer a classe 1 e praticamente `0.0` de pertencer a classe 2.
- `[9.7...e-01, 2.8...e-02, ...e-08]`, ou seja, `0.97` de pertencer a classe 0, `0.028` de pertencer a classe 1 e praticamente `0.0` de pertencer a classe 2.